# How do I apply the same IF statements to multiple cells in the same column? (EXCEL)

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, macros

I'm currently working on a macro to create a matrix of different products and option codes for work.  Most of the information I need has already been exported from an order creation system we run.  One of the things that does not export, however, are the descriptions for the roughly 150 option codes.  Each option code comes with a description that is outlined in a separate worksheet, so instead of having to always refer back to the other worksheet I have decided to program the descriptions into the code using IF statements.  My goal is to write a program that looks at each option code in the column, then insert the matching description of that option code in the adjacent column.

For example:
My program would say:  If the active cell says "AAAAA" then select the cell one unit offset horizontally and insert "Option 1".  Else, if it says "BBBBB", then insert a another option description.

Since our product orders are always changing and I need to present this info for roughly 3000 products per week, I need to know how I can type my conditions once, then insert a piece of code that will tell the program to carry it out for next (X) number of options in the column, or as long as the cells have data in them.

I'm pretty sure a loop would solve my problem but I have yet been able to find a loop script that satisfies my requirements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Option_Matrix_2()
'Enters data for Option code Description into worksheet
Range("G4").Select
If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AAAA" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description 1"



ElseIf ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CCCCC" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description 2"


ElseIf ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EEEEE" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description 3"

 Else
 ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""

End If
```

Since I have over 3000 products and 150 different options, I need to know what I need to insert to tell the macro to run the code for each cell in the column that contains data.  In this case it would be ("G4:G3000")

If there is any other information that is required please let me know I'd be happy to help in any way I can

Comment: Build a cross-reference lookup table and match. tbh, I don't see why the native worksheet [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) could not be used unless you **want** to write out ~150 different scenarios.

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, that's actually a really good point.  It's just that I have to create this matrix usually about 10 times per week to satisfy different requests that my managers make of me to see certain products, options, etc.  So it just eliminates a step for me by having the information written out in VBA as opposed to attaching the table every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what @Jeeped suggested in the comments but if you really want to do it in vba then:

```
Private Sub Option_Matrix_2()
Dim cl As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
'Enters data for Option code Description into worksheet
For Each cl In ws.Range("G4:G3000")
    If cl.FormulaR1C1 = "AAAA" Then
        cl.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Description 1"
    ElseIf cl.FormulaR1C1 = "CCCCC" Then
        cl.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Description 2"
    ElseIf cl.FormulaR1C1 = "EEEEE" Then
        cl.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Description 3"
    Else
    cl.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ""
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Or better yet use Select Case:

```
Private Sub Option_Matrix_2()
Dim cl As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
'Enters data for Option code Description into worksheet
For Each cl In ws.Range("G4:G3000")
    Select Case cl
        Case "AAAA": cl.Offset(, 1) = "Description 1"
        Case "CCCC": cl.Offset(, 1) = "Description 2"
        Case "EEEE": cl.Offset(, 1) = "Description 3"
        Case Else: cl.Offset(, 1) = ""
    End Select
Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Option_Matrix_3()

With Sheets("Sheet01").Range("G4:G3000") ' change to your actual sheet name and range
    .Copy
    With .Offset(, 1)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        .Replace What:="AAAA", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="Description 1", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        .Replace What:="CCCCC", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="Description 2", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        .Replace What:="EEEEE", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="Description 3", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

seems quite fast!